# How to run cppcheck in powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, bamboo

I'm trying to run a static code checker (cppcheck) on a checked out code from a repo. Here is the powershell script that the agent would like the agent to run in bamboo but it always fails and I don't get why. I've already tried multiple versions that I've found on the internet but none of them worked so far.

```
'C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe' cppcheck --enable=all --xml-version=2 source 2>&1 | Out-File cppcheck_ps.xml

cppcheck --enable=all --xml-version=2 source 2>&1 | Out-File cppcheck_ps.xml
(it is added to the path)

'C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe' cppcheck --enable=all --xml-version=2 source 2> | Out-File cppcheck_ps.xml


& 'C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe' cppcheck --enable=all --xml-version=2 source 2>&1 | Out-File cppcheck_ps.xml
```

either it doesn't accept the `&` or the `|` symbols.

Comment: *"it always fails"*  What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: You definitely need `&` before the executable path, given that the path is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The second one should work if cppcheck is in the path. The last one should work without having cppcheck twice. What's the error? You can also backtick the space:

```
C:\Program` Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe
```

Comment: the error was that it didnt recognize the & or the | operator and this was due to the fact that i was calling this command in shell not powershell (the switch in bamboo) thank you for your help, next time i'll be more careful!